# Delete file with same name contained in different sub-folders

Tags: windows, recursion, cmd

For some reason, I have a copy of `dismhost.exe` in a lot of folders, inside `temp` folder; what I want to do is delete every instance of it, which are inside folders inside `temp`.

So the structure is as follows:

```
/temp
 /folder1
  dismhost.exe
 /folder2
  dismhost.exe
 /folder3
  dismhost.exe
 ...
```

I first tried

```
rm ./*/dismhost.exe
```

but then I remembered there is no `rm` in windows, so I tried with `rd` with same arguments. That raised an error, saying that the `*` modifier is not valid.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using a FOR loop iterating over a list of files returned by a recursive DIR search. When you are satisfied with the output, remove `ECHO` in order to actually delete the files.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %f IN (`DIR /S /B /A:-D \temp\dismhost.exe`) DO (ECHO DEL "%~f")
```

If this is placed into a .bat script, be sure to double the % characters on the variable.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f IN (`DIR /S /B /A:-D \temp\dismhost.exe`) DO (
    ECHO DEL "%%~f"
)
```

Comment: I had to delete `\temp` from the path, but everything else works like a charm.

Comment: this is bloody great!

Answer (score 0):

Or use recursive delete.:

```
del /s \temp\dismhost.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows

To delete a single file, use the following command:

```
del C:\enter\your\path\here /f /s
```

remove a specific file type from a folder:

```
del *.extension
```

Swap out "extension" for the file type you want to remove.

You can extend the command to delete all of the specific file extension from subfolders with the addition of a couple of parameters:

```
del /s /q *.extension
```

if you want to delete multiple file types, you can add multiple extension types:

```
del /s /q *.png *.svg
```

If you want to files along with folders remove, you can use the following commands:

```
del /f /s /q C:\enter\your\path\here > nul

rmdir /s /q C:\enter\your\path\here
```